# How to store an array on sysfs in Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, sysfs

I am writing Linux Kernel module, where I'm creating some sysfs files to store variables.

But I need to implement arrays, something like:

```
struct ats {
   struct attribute attr;
   unsigned long value[5];
};

struct ats m_ats = {
   .attr.name="m_ats",
   .attr.mode = 0644,
   .value[0] = 0,
   .value[1] = 0,
   .value[2] = 0,
   .value[3] = 0,
   .value[4] = 0,
};
```

Is there a way to do that? How would be the show, store, module_init, module_exit functions?

Comment: are you asking if there is a way to point to functions? `"How would be the show, store, module_init, module_exit functions?"`

Comment: no, I'm asking how to implement these functions. What difference exist between normal variable store on sysfs and array one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it *manually*. You can use `sscanf` on the incoming string, parse the input and store each value in the array slot. Something like this:

```
sscanf(input_string, "%d %d %d", value[0], value[1], value[3])
```

Comment: Isn't there another way? for example, the loopN files on _/sys/block_ : _loop0_ , _loop1_ and so on, are all created by hand?

Comment: they are created automatically when a `loop` block device occur. But this is not what you are asking for. You asked for attributes, and in your example you are talking about blocks devices